# NPE Intent calling in phone gap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins

I'm stack on understanding next problem:
Have PG application which get img from canvas. My plugin save this image on SD. Also i'm try to call intent ACTION_SEND but get NPE on LogCat.
Code in plugin:

> public void oper(String imageFile) {
>
> ```
>   Intent intent = new Intent();   
>   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>     intent.setType("*/*");      
>   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageFile) );    
>   startActivity(intent);   }
> ```

Next step of my research was calling another activity(class) from app.

> Intent intent=new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
>
> startActivity(intent);

Take same issue.
How i can realized calling of Intent from plugin(java class)?

Comment: And can anyone explain why this intent not calling by this method of realization?

Comment: Two days i'm trying to find how to solve it but can't to do this!!!
And only after few minutes after publication get it:

    Actually code:
       cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {//
                     @Override
      public void run() {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
     intent.setType("*/*");  
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(stringUri) );
     cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
     Log.d("my tag", "after the install action");
     }
    });

Hope it's help for someone else